# Gather info from OSM using Overpy and Python: issue in gathering results in table form

Tags: python, json, overpass-api

I am using Overpass query to gather info about the lenght of dfferent type of ways in a given box identified through coordinates. I managed to do it using OverPass Turbo but I am having troubles doing it in Python.

In Overpass I was able to write the following query:

```
[out:csv(length,value)];
way[highway](50.6,7.0,50.8,7.3);
for (t["highway"])
{
  make stat value=_.val,length=sum(length());
  out;
}
```

This query gives me a table with two columns (lenght and value) that I like. However, I am having troubles implementing it in python using overpy. Of course this could not work:

```
import overpy
api = overpy.Overpass()

query_result = api.query("""
[out:csv(length,value)];
way[highway](50.6,7.0,50.8,7.3);
for (t["highway"])
{
  make stat value=_.val,length=sum(length());
  out;
}
    """)
```

So I tried to export it in JSON

```
query_result = api.query("""
[out:json];
way[highway](50.6,7.0,50.8,7.3);
for (t["highway"])
{
  make stat value=_.val,length=sum(length());
  out;
}
    """)
```

And it kinda work (I guess) because i get: `<overpy.Result at 0x7fcbfd659610>`

However, now I do not know how to access the data as I had it in Overpass. `query_result.node` `query_result.ways` and `query_result.relations` give empty sets. I also tried `query_result.get_elements` or `query_result['elements']` but I could not access the data.

So I am asking how can I correctly retrieve data and put it like in a csv file/pandas dataframe as shown for Overpass?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to loop through your `query_result` to access the ways and the nodes, and then turn the data to whatever format you want.

e.g.

```
for highway in query_result.ways: 
  # Each iteration should give you the way
  for node in highway.nodes:
    # Each iteration should give you the node the value
```